# Firestore deadlock when using transaction.get(query)

Tags: java, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

I am using Firestore Admin SDK for Java.

I get a deadlock if I do something like:

```
repeat(100) {
    firestore.runTransaction { transaction ->
        val docSnapshot = transaction.get(query)
                .get()
                .documents
                .singleOrNull()

        // Use docSnapshot
    }
}
```

The deadlock with happen on `get` call. On the other hand, if I query outside the transaction, and only get a document snapshot inside the transaction via reference, there is no deadlock.

Why? Is there anything wrong with my approach?

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to accomplish with the code you've given.  What do you expect it to do?

Comment: I am running ~100 transactions in parallel which update different documents in the same collection.

Comment: What different documents?  What is `query` again?  Seems like you need to pass a document, not a query.